# How do I find the chat room?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

I once managed to chat with someone instead of writing a lot of comments because the site proposed that to me.

I have a really hard time finding and using the chat on this site. Maybe one could make this very useful feature more readily available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. A direct link to the [hbar chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) appears e.g. in the right margin on [the front page](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/) of the [physics meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/).
2. Alternatively, the [hbar chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) can be [found](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=physics.stackexchange.com) on [chat.stackexchange.com](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).
3. From *any* page on the [physics main site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) or the [physics meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/), single-click on the word 'StackExchange' in the upper left corner of the page. A menu should open. A click on the word 'chat' near the top of the menu brings you to [chat.stackexchange.com](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Continue with item 2.

[image]